# ASP.NET Disable button and run the function

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I am facing this issue where I manage to disable button but somehow the function didn't run. I suspect that the function stops right after my button is disabled. Any idea that can solve this issue when user click on the button, the button will be disable immediately and the button will runs the function behind. Below are the codes that I'm using for my button.

```
<INPUT TYPE ="Submit" NAME ="Submit1" ID = "Submit1" VALUE ="Create New Sales Contract" 
       SIZE ="30" onclick="**this.disabled=true;*** CheckGWidth(this.form), 
       this.form.ContractType.value='N'*" >
```

Note:

1. this.disabled=true; To disable this button
2. CheckGWidth(this.form),this.form.ContractType.value='N'

This is a function that will process this page'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling a button won't stop the rest of the code from firing.  I suspect there is something else going on.

This works using `document.getElementById` instead of `this.form`:

```
<form id="form1" action="" method="post">
    <INPUT TYPE ="submit" NAME ="Submit1" ID = "Submit1" VALUE ="Create New Sales Contract" SIZE ="30" onclick="this.disabled=true;CheckGWidth(this.form);document.getElementById('ContractType').value='N';return false;" />
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="ContractType" ID="ContractType" /> 
</form>

<script>
    function CheckGWidth(f){
        alert("This works");
    }
</script>
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NN2Cx/)

Use Firebug or Chrome or Developer Tools and check your javascript issues...

Comment: Hi there, that is not the issue, it works fine with both comma and semicolon. Disabling a button won't stop the function? But in my case I think it does :(

Comment: @TanSiongZhe -- Take a look here (seems to work -- I used document.getElementById): http://jsfiddle.net/NN2Cx/

Comment: Will let u know the outcome later. Thank you so much.

Comment: So sad and too bad it doesn't work. So strange that I encountered this issue. By the way, your button didn't re-enable.

Comment: @TanSiongZhe -- Hmmm, I imagine your issues are in your CheckGWidth function then.  Did the jsFiddle work for you?  It did 3 things -- disable the button, alert (whatever your function does) and the set the value of a field.  I don't see anything in your post about re-enabling the button.

Comment: Re-enabling the button isn't in my priority list so no worries. The function basically just check for validation only.